# How is energy conserved in case of gravitational acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

If two uniform moving bodies in space are at some point accelerated towards each other due to gravity then their kinetic energies increase and their potential energies decrease and when they collide all of the kinetic energy is converted into internal energy. But this amount of internal energy is greater than the kinetic energy of their initial speeds. How then is energy conserved?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your starting conditions?  For example, consider the situation in which the two objects are initially at rest. Take the center of mass frame. No kinetic energy. The final state in an inelastic collision also has no kinetic energy, but the internal energy is greater than zero.   Is this an example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is conserved because there were initially *more* energy present than just their kinetic energies $K$: also gravitational potential energy $U$ was present.

$$\require{cancel}E_{\text{internal},1}+K_1+U_1=E_{\text{internal},2}+K_2+U_2\\
-\Delta K-\Delta U=\Delta E_\text{internal}$$

The change in internal energy is equal to not just the total drop in kinetic energy but also to the drop in gravitational potential energy that has now been converted into internal energy.

---

Since it is mentioned in the comments that the initial gravitational potential energy amount is zero, we can simplify the expression to:

$$\require{cancel}E_{\text{internal},1}+K_1+\cancel{U_1}=E_{\text{internal},2}+K_2+U_2\\
-\Delta K-U_2=\Delta E_\text{internal}$$

The final potential energy amount ends up negative (below zero, since we started at zero when far away). This expression thus clearly shows an increase in the internal energy.

Comment: But I assume they approach each other from infinity U=0.

Comment: @Jack In that case I shouldn't have cancelled out the second potential energy term. I have updated the answer. The potential energy may have started at zero, but it ends *below* zero. Meaning, there is a drop. This drop is taken converted into internal energy, just like the kinetic energy drop.

Comment: At the start we can measure kinetic energy after the collision (totally inelastic) we can measure the internal energy. Nothing else can be measured and we don't find $E_1=E_2$. The potential energy is an artifact.

Comment: The thing is, it depends on your choice of reference for the zero-point of the gravitational potential energy. Can we agree that there is a difference in potentiale energy between the objects being infinitely far apart and the objects being close together? If you choose far apart to corresponds to zero then what is the value close together? It can't also be zero. In fact, it is negative. You are able to "measure" it when close together just as easily/difficult as you can "measure" it when far apart.

Comment: The thing is that you define $\Delta K=-\Delta U$ and then you have a tautology that always works. But what I show is that the initial kinetic energy + internal energy < internal energy after collision, or what is the same the universe is heated up just due gravity. Of course the quantity of motion which is only measured perfectly with momentum has not changed.

Comment: @Jack What does the $\Delta U$ represent in your formula?

Comment: what? "Of course the quantity of motion which is only measured perfectly with momentum has not changed"  acceleration force is dp/dt and mα,  so acceleration leads to a change in momentum.

Comment: @Steeven $\Delta U$ is change in potential energy. Which creates the tautology $\Delta K+\Delta U=0$.

Comment: @Jack Your equation $$\Delta K=−\Delta U$$ does not include internal energy then. How do you with this formula arrive at a result that shows that the change in internal energy is larger than the change in kinetic energy? In fact since you have an increase in kinetic energy in your scenario, then this formula directly tells that the potential energy must *decrease*. If it starts out at zero, then it must become negative.

Comment: @Jack The formula $\Delta K=-\Delta U$ is usually called the **work (kinetic) energy theorem**. It is a simplified version of the energy conservation law. It only applies when no other energy types than kinetic and potential are involved and when the internal energy doesn't change. This is common in mechanics e.g. which is where this formula is mostly used. If you have a change in internal energy, then this formula does not apply.

Comment: My point is that $\Delta U$ can't be measured it is just defined as the negative of the work done by a conservative force, but you are right mathematically the result is that initial en final total energy is the same. I just don't like the fact that if you measure the initial energy (kinetic) and the final energy (kinetic + internal)  then it is increased.

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure what the issue is exactly. If you measure the **initial energy**, then you should in this case measure/calculate the kinetic energy. Yes, agreed. If you measure the **final energy**, then you should measure/calculate the kinetic energy, the internal energy *and* the gravitational potential energy. Why are you leaving out the potential energy term here? I get it that you don't like it, but I don't understand why. Potential energy is just as valid an energy form as, say, kinetic.

Comment: Momentum is a quantity of motion. The total amount is a constant in the universe it is only exchanged between  objects (either matter or radiation). So we have only objects in motion. Now kinetic energy is another quantity of motion. But to have conservation we need to introduce a conservative field and potential energy. To me these are not real in a universe of only matter and radiation and exchange of motion. Suppose in the example we have an elastic collision, then the masses reverse direction and increase their potential energy forever which seems absurd.

Comment: @Jack Their kinetic energies will also decrease forever. I don't see how that seems less absurd. Energy in general is quite counterintuitive - that there are various forms of energy is all equally abstract in my view. But anyways, regardless of how absurd it seems, to solve your task we must acknowledge potential energy as well.